# undeclared variable in php why through error?

Tags: php

As described in php manual

> It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a very good practice. Uninitialized variables have a default value of their type depending on the context in which they are used - booleans default to FALSE, integers and floats default to zero, strings (e.g. used in echo) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an empty array

if so then why its through error (notice) when try to access uninitialized variable? like

```
echo $x;
```

its return even in script following message

> Notice: Undefined variable: x...

But When I declare `$x` as `NULL` then its not through any notice or error and working nicely

```
$x = NULL;
echo $x;
```

**Now My Question** is Why its through notice if not declare like `$x = NULL` or `$x = ''` although undeclared variable initialized as `NULL` which is clearly mentioned in Manual??

I have a script and many uninitialized variable there and experiencing this issue.

Comment: Are you using the same version of PHP that you're looking at the manual for?

Comment: Try changing the version of your PHP

Comment: I am using php 5.6.8 and quotation from online manual.

Comment: Mine's okay if i print that. My php version is 5.6.3

Answer (score 4):

Well I think you will need to understand better the variable life cycle. Since PHP is a run time interpreted language uses late binding; For example:

```
$null=null;
$empty="";
$true=true;
unset($undefined);
```

This will result:

```
isset($undefined): false
empty($undefined): true
is_null($undefined): true

isset($null): false
empty($null): true
is_null($null): true

isset($empty): true
empty($empty): true
is_null($empty): false

isset($true): true
empty($true): false
is_null($true): false
```

From this you can see that there is not difference from null variables to undefined ones.

Solution:

Use `isset` to prevent those warnings

Comment: Which will be faster? `isset($x)` or `$x = NULL`. Any idea? my app is real time so performance does matter.

Comment: Well when I test both scenarios the result is the same speed, 140ms per execution. You have to remember that in both cases is just testing if there any references to that point in memory. nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you do an echo with $x uninitialized throws warning because these variable doesn't have any memory reserve.

In the other case, when you do $x=null you are reserving memory for $x variable although you don't give it value.

Comment: when `$x = NULL` then how much memory it reserve?

Comment: Please check this sample http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea22efd7e1c1c44bad9783d5ae3b155b3dea1332

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge difference between declaration and initialization. You need to declare a variable before you can use it but you dont necesarrily have to initialize it.